# MongoEngine raw query not solved

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Mongo engine cannot execute a raw query

```
AppDocument.objects(__raw__={
{"_id": ObjectId("1"),"car._id": ObjectId("2")}, 
            {"$pull": 
                {"car.$.toys": {"_id": ObjectId("3")}}
            }
}
```

The error is :

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Answer (score 2):

`.objects()` is used only for querying, not updating. Thus, `__raw__` only let you force the `filter` part of the query, not the `update` part.

The way you need to do that with mongoengine:

```
find_qry = {"_id": ObjectId("1"),"car._id": ObjectId("2")}
update_qry = {"$pull": {"car.$.toys": {"_id": ObjectId("3")}}}
AppDocument.objects(__raw__=find_qry).update(__raw__=update_qry)
```

Alternatively, note that you can always reach the underlying pymongo collection

```
coll = AppDocument._get_collection()
coll.update(find_qry, update_query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove '{ }' extras

```
AppDocument.objects(__raw__=
{"_id": ObjectId("1"),"car._id": ObjectId("2")}, 
            {"$pull": 
                {"car.$.toys": {"_id": ObjectId("3")}}
            }
```